# Storing data in the React public folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storage

Currently for demo purposes I have a total of 1GB worth of .mp4/pdf files in my React public folder. I reference these files via props (example: `file={'/40246/${this.props.showPdf}'}`, but eventually these files are going to become larger and I am looking at maybe 50-100GB of .mp4/pdf files in the public folder.

Is it okay to have such large files in the public folder, will compile time of my app take forever?

I have also researched about ejecting the react app and referencing the files from outside the React src folder, but do not want the hassle of managing or configuring webpacks when something goes wrong. Actually I tried it and my app immediately crashed after npm start

Any advice or specific documentation I should look into would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you thinking about sending 100GB to the client's browser? (It is not okay)

Comment: No, but each video/pdf when loaded will be around 10GB, can't load more than one of each on the application. 100GB is just the estimated total size of all the files

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any process associated for public assets, it just copies the files over to the `build` folder. There won't be any impact on performance during the build process.

Demo: check both files(`demo.mov`), it just copied the file from `public` to `build` with the following command: `yarn build prod`
[image]

Comment: thanks for the response, the app will end up being in a docker container and I was wondering if multiple people use the application will the videos/pdf load slower or will there not be significant change?

Comment: The server will retrieve the file for each user, especially video's can require quite a lot of compute and bandwidth because each user streams it from the server. After retrieving the files the browser will cache them for a bit. You could look into configuring the cache headers for optimal caching to reduce server load. An alternative would be to look into CDN for serving the static files.

Comment: would you know any key words i can look up on google or documentation to search on how to get React to access files from a server?

Comment: You already mentioned using docker, where are you running your docker container?

Comment: on a local server i believe, then will be moved to a linux vm

Comment: When running your static react site I would recommend using Nginx to serve the files. If the bandwidth on the server is limited or expensive you should look into using a CDN like digitalocean spaces, cloudfront(AWS), cloudflare CDN, Azure CDN. They are made to serve static files and are located close to end-users to speed up the download process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206664/discussion-between-prav-and-maartendev).